# Screen wakes up with a big delay after sleep mode on Ubuntu 22.04 Dell XPS 13 9310

Tags: suspend, dell, screen, xps

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9310 for more than one year now without any problem. [But now I'm facing two !](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482375/bluetooth-suddenly-stopped-to-work-with-22-04-on-dell-xps-13-9310)
But since a few days, when I turn on the sleep mode (manually or by closing my computer) and then try to wake up my computer, it will do it but after a very long minute of black screen even if my keyboard succeeded in that wake-up.

I'm using Wayland, I tried on X11, but there is the same problem.
Do you think I can repair my sleep mode-wake up without reinstalling the hole system ?

Thanks in advance for your help !
Nans

---

Here are the results of some commands that might help :

```
lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 '\''[030[02]\]' | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|kernel"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

```
uname -a
Linux NilsXPS13 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 180mm
   1920x1200     59.88*+
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

```
dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                                        Version                                         Architecture Description
+++-==========================================-===============================================-============-================================================================================
hi  thunderbird                                1:91.8.0+build2-0ubuntu1                        amd64        Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
```

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

```
journalctl --no-pager -b -p err
août 15 00:20:54 NilsXPS13 kernel: x86/mktme: No known encryption algorithm is supported: 0x0
août 15 00:20:55 NilsXPS13 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
août 15 00:20:55 NilsXPS13 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
août 15 00:20:55 NilsXPS13 gnome-session-binary[1219]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 15 00:20:55 NilsXPS13 gnome-session-binary[1219]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
août 15 00:20:57 NilsXPS13 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device boot timeout
août 15 00:20:58 NilsXPS13 canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1076]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/56be800040b24ae1b20429d83c89b045/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
août 15 00:20:59 NilsXPS13 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-110)
août 15 00:20:59 NilsXPS13 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc1e tx timeout
août 15 00:21:02 NilsXPS13 gdm-password][1892]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
août 15 00:21:03 NilsXPS13 systemd[1902]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
août 15 00:21:03 NilsXPS13 systemd[1902]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
août 15 00:21:03 NilsXPS13 systemd[1902]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
août 15 00:21:04 NilsXPS13 systemd[1902]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
août 15 00:21:04 NilsXPS13 systemd[1902]: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
août 15 00:21:06 NilsXPS13 gdm-launch-environment][1154]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

```
ls -l /var/crash
total 100880
-rw-r----- 1 nils     whoopsie 71096781 août  11 19:53 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 nils     whoopsie   220635 août  14 23:47 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 nils     whoopsie 31970367 août   8 12:20 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nils     whoopsie        0 août   8 12:20 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 août   8 12:21 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: Sorry no answer.
But I have the same issue which seemed to arrive with the upgrade to 6.2.0.26 Jim

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have disappeared with 6.2.0-32
well at least it has on mine.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue for the first time today.  Possible clue is that yesterday I enabled ipV6, and have valid ipv6 addresses.

Today after letting the computer sleep, it woke up with just a large number 8 on the screen.  The normal screen was distorted but I was able to click in the upper right and do a shutdown.  Now it's back to 'normal'.

Linux lisa-Legion-Y545-PG0 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1332380)