# Bluetooth suddenly stopped to work with 22.04 on Dell XPS 13 9310

Tags: bluetooth, dell, xps

I've been using Ubuntu for more than one year without any problem. [But now I'm facing two !](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1482342/revisions)

I was able to normally turn ON/OFF my bluetooth and to connect my computer to any device.
But now, if the bluetooth parameter is still available, there is no way I can turn it ON.
The switcher switcher, but does not turn orange and the bluetooth stays OFF.

I tried to boot on a flas drive with Ubuntu on it, the problem was the same : the bluetooth did not work (but I didn't face any sleep mode-wake up issue).

I do not understand, since my bluetooth used to work until now...

What can I do to get it back working ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
nans

---

This is what I tried without any good result :
(My bluetooth device is ON in the BIOS menu)

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ rfkill list
```

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ hcitool dev
```

Devices:

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ hcitool inq
```

Inquiring ...
Inquiry failed.: No such device

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth && rfkill list bluetooth
```

[sudo] Mot de passe de nans :
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

Can't set scan mode on hci0: Network is down (100)

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

```
nans@nansXPS13:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd

nans@nansXPS13:~$ sudo reboot
```